# RegEx Expression for validating Phone number while creating a Lead

Tags: leads

My lead creation is failing via the REST Api due to invalid phone number. Below is the error response:

`Error Code: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION; Error Message: Please use the international phone number format for the Fax field (eg: +49...) Use only Numbers, space, point and the negative sign.`

Can you tell me if there is any Regular Expression that i can validate with before sending the data to Salesforce or is there any other method that i can validate the Phone number?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334073&type=1&mode=1 this shows many options and ways. Try the same.

Comment: @YsrShk Don't we have a regular expression for all the countries? I understand each country has different patterns. Any idea how it is validated in the Salesforce API?

Comment: [e.164 regex](https://support.secureauth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036402211-Regular-Expressions-for-ITU-E-123-and-E-164-phone-number-formats) - but personally, i'd accept any string and normalize to e.164 in a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the below regex to validate the phone number:
\D*?(\d\D*?){5,}